# Using read.zoo instead of read.table and zoo()?

Tags: r, time-series, zoo

I have a file with many rows of this kind

```
2010-01-12 19:40   1021.00000   0.00001     1.00
2010-01-12 19:50   1031.00000   0.00000     -1.00
```

In order to read it as zoo I use

```
tmp <- read.table("myfile")
GOEMD <- zoo(tmp[,3], as.chron(paste(tmp[,1],tmp[,2]), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))
```

that works properly
But I'd like to use `read.zoo()` instead.

I've tried

```
f <- function(x)  as.chron(paste(tmp[,1],tmp[,2]))
tmp <- read.zoo("myfile", index = 1:2, sep=" ", FUN  = f)
```

and even specifying

```
colClasses= c("character","character","numeric","numeric","numeric")
```

but it doesn't work;
it says: 
line 136 (the one I've pasted above) doesn't have 14 elements.

I've also tried:

```
tmp <- read.zoo("myfile", index = 1:2, sep=" ", FUN  = as.chron)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The typo in `f` was already pointed out.
2. Also there are a few features of `read.zoo` that you might wish to take advantage of.  Firstly, note that if the value of the `index` argument is a list then the columns referenced in each component of that list are passed as separate arguments to `FUN`.  Also note that a `FUN2` argument is available which is applied to the output of `FUN` so we can write it in a compact fashion like this:

Thus try this:

```
library(zoo)
library(chron)

Lines <- "2010-01-12 19:40   1021.00000   0.00001     1.00
2010-01-12 19:50   1031.00000   0.00000     -1.00"

z <- read.zoo(textConnection(Lines), index = list(1, 2), 
        FUN = paste, FUN2 = as.chron)
```

The above was written to be self contained so you could just copy it verbatim to the clipboard and then paste it into your R session.  To use it with your file replace `textConnection(Lines)` with `"myfile"`.

Comment: Hi. It works.  But how can I read only the first 3 rows, I mean in the same line. If I have a variable I write  myvar[1:3], but how can I do it directly with a filename?.  cheers

Comment: I found the way:  read.zoo("myfile.txt", colClasses = c("character", "character", "numeric", "numeric", "NULL"),index = list(1, 2),  FUN = paste, FUN2 = as.chron)

Answer (score 2):

Your function `f` has to search for `tmp`.  You probably intended:

```
f <- function(x)  as.chron(paste(x[,1],x[,2]))
tmp <- read.zoo("myfile", index = 1:2, sep=" ", FUN = f)
```

Also, the sample data you posted looks like it's tab-delimited, not space-delimited, so you may need to this instead:

```
tmp <- read.zoo("myfile", index = 1, sep="\t", FUN = as.chron)
```